# How to do group by based on another column in SELECT?

Tags: sql-server, select, subquery

I have a table on which I do a SELECT statement. It is joined to some other tables. With the SELECT one column is got but a sub query. like `(select top 1 .. from..)` for each row. Now I need to do an aggregation based on that column, so I have to group by id(which I also select) the amounts that I've got in that column got by the subquery. Is it possible and how?
I use MS SQL Server

Comment: Not clear requirements. It would be best if you edited the question and added: Which DBMS you use (we guess SQL Server) and which version (2012, 2014, 2017, etc). The CREATE TABLE statement of the tables needed. Samples (of a few rows) from each table (in text format). Finally, the wanted output (and the query you tried,even if it gives you an error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your requirements, but I guess you do something like:

```
select (select top 1 .. from...), count(...)
from ...
...
```

It's probably easiest to first select everything in a derived table or a CTE, and then aggregate from there:

```
select x, count(1)
from (
    select (select top 1 ... from ...) as x
         , ...
    from ...
    ...
) as t
group by x
```